# Prove Bipartite theorem by illustration

Tags: graph-theory

I am given the bipartite theorem : A graph G is bipartite IFF G has no odd cycles.

The proof is given.

I need to illustrate both sides of the proof.

IE: illustrate the proof that if G is bipartite it has no odd cycles
 AND 
    illustrate the proof that if G has no odd cycles, it is bipartite.

I don't know how to go about this.

I am thinking that for part 2 of the proof, I will draw any G with odd cycle, and show it is not bipartite.

However I'm not sure if this is enough and I don't know how to illustrate part 1 of the proof.

Comment: I think it is required to prove that being bipartite is equivalent to having no odd cycles. No counterexamples are required, just prove both directions.

Comment: You say that you’re given the proof, so I assume that the problem is not just to reproduce or explain that proof. Is *illustrate* here to be taken literally? Are you supposed to produce an illustration, an actual picture showing an example of what’s going on in that part of the proof?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott my understanding is to illustrate literally, since the proof is already given to me.  I thought to do so by colouring vertices. I am still uncertain how to actually illustrate though.  I thought to start with the assumption that I have a 2-colourable graph G with an odd cycle v1v2...vn.  Colour v1 red, v2 blue, therefore v3 must be red.  This pattern shows that odd vertices are red, even vertices are blue. The vertex before v1 must be odd since it is an odd cycle, therefore it must be red.  This shows the cycle is not 2-colourable, therefore not bipartite.

Comment: @Amr There are actually two questions that I am given.  The first question I have to answer asks to illustrate part 1 of the proof (IE going in one direction) and the second question I have to answer is to illustrate part 2 of the proof (IE going in the other direction)

Comment: You’ve a reasonable idea for the direction *bipartite implies no odd cycles*; I’ve suggested a possible improvement in my answer. How to illustrate the other direction, though, depends a bit on just how it was proved. Can you outline the proof of *no odd cycles implies bipartite* that you were given?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott let $G$ be a connected graph that contains no odd cycles. and let $x$ be an arbitrary vertex in $G$  and let  $A = \bigcup_{i \geq 0} N_{2i}(x) $  and $  B = \bigcup_{i \geq 0} N_{2i+1} (x) $  So A has all the vertices in $G$ that are an even distance from $x$ and B has all the vertices that are an odd distance from $x$.  Assume A has 2 adjacent vertices, $u, v$.  No vertex in $N_{2i}$ is adjacent to any vertex in $N_{2j}$ if $i\not= j$ so $u$ and $v$ must be in the same distance set.There is a path $P$ from $u$ to $x$ and a path $Q$ from $v$ to $x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott let $y$ be the first vertex that $P$ and $Q$ have in common. $y \in N_{j}(x) 0 \leq j \leq 2k-1$. $y$ could be $x$. Let $P'$ be the subpath of $P$ starting at $u$ and ending at $y$, $Q'$ is the subpath of $Q$ starting at $v$ ending at $y$.  Now $G$ has a cycle consisting of paths $P'$ and $Q'$ and the edge $uv$.  Since $P'$ and $Q'$ have the same length, the cycle has an odd length, this contradicts our assumption. So the vertices in $A$ are mutually independent in $G$. The same can be proved for $B$. So $(A,B)$ is a bipartition of $G$

Answer (score 1):

For one direction you could draw a graph with an odd cycle, perhaps a $5$-cycle, since a triangle might seem too special, and anything bigger will be too much work. Make five copies of the graph, and draw the vertices as circles, small but not too small. In the first graph color one of the vertices in the cycle red, say. In the second, color it red and one of its neighbors blue. In the next two pictures color the next two vertices in the cycle red and blue, respectively. And in the last picture show the last vertex split in two, with one side blue (adjacent to the first red vertex) and one side red (adjacent to the last blue vertex). That, it seems to me, illustrates reasonably well the essential problem created by an odd cycle. This illustrates the *bipartite implies no odd cycles* direction.

An illustration for the other direction depends on just how that proof was done.

**Added:** For this you might start with a bipartite graph with parts $A$ and $B$, but don’t draw it in the usual way, with the vertices in $A$ lined up opposite the vertices in $B$ and all of the edges crossing between the two lines of vertices. Pick one vertex in $A$ and call it $x$. Then draw $N_1(x)$ around $x$, $N_2(x)$ outside that, and so on, so that the vertices are arranged more or less in concentric rings around $x$. Color the vertices of $A$ red and those of $B$ blue. Pick two vertices of $N_6$, say, and draw in a dotted edge between them; they’re the $u$ and $v$ of the proof. Mark the paths $P$ and $Q$ in contrasting colors; to make it interesting, have them meet at some vertex $y$ in $N_3(x)$, say. Then you can mark the edges of the cycle alternately with two different treatments, starting at $u$ and going around through $y$ to $v$. Half of the edge $uv$ will have to be marked one way and half the other; this ‘collision’ shows pretty clearly that the cycle is odd.